# Symfony & document root через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, symfony2, symfony

Всем привет.
Разбираюсь с Symfony. Пытаюсь настроить document root для Symfony через htaccess, чтобы в пути не нужно было вводить `/web/` (для случаев, если нет возможности настройки сервера). Прописал:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/ 
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [QSA]
```

Главная страница открывается. Но когда добавляю другую страницу - некорректно определяется GET в фреймворке. В моем случае адрес `http://domain.ru/app_dev.php/lucky/number`, т.е. роут - `lucky/number`, выдает ошибку `No route found for "GET ky/number"`, т.е. где-то съедает `luc`, просто для теста попробовал `http://domain.ru/app_dev.php/111/lucky/number` - открывается страница.

Как это можно исправить? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на свой вопрос нашел [здесь](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html)

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения, чтобы он был самодостаточным.